# How do I allow other (mac) machines to access an IIS7 hosted MVC3 application on my (win7)machine?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, macos, asp.net-mvc-3, windows-7, iis-7.5

I am trying to make my MVC application accessible on other computers, specifically mac machines. This is my first time to run a site on IIS7 because I got used to the older version of IIS on winXP at work. While on this computer I just usually use VS2010's development server.

I am using windows7 (64bit) and I want to access this site on a mac / other machines.

My site bindings setup are as follows:
Type: http
IP address: All Unassigned
Port: 80
Host name: www.thisisatest.com

ON MY MACHINE:
 I can access www.thisisatest.com but not COMPUTERNAME/www.thisisatest.com or IPADDRESS/www.thisisatest.com which I think supposedly should work because I've done this many times in our office on winXP.

But I can access the IIS7 page with COMPUTERNAME/ or IPADDRESS/

ON ANOTHER MACHINE (MAC):
 I'm getting the Server Not Responding error when I try to access IPADDRESS/

My firewall is already turned off and I've already added an Inbound Rule on my firewall to open all ports.

Questions:

1.Why can't I access the site using COMPUTERNAME/www.thisisatest.com or IPADDRESS/www.thisisatest.com even on my own machine? This is weird because it is my own machine where my app is hosted.

2.What should I do to allow remote access? Does it matter if it's a mac machine that I'm using to access the site?

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens when you access `http://IPADDRESS/` on a Mac? You mentioned you accessed `IPADDRESS/` so I'm not sure if that is on http or as a lan share... Also is IPADDRESS a lan one (192... or 10.) or a public one? Is your Mac in the same lan as the IIS or you're trying to access over the internet?

Comment: I'm getting the Server Not Responding error when I try to access htp://IPADDRESS/ on my Mac. Both my windows and mac machine are connecting on the same router. Sorry I didn't includ "http://" on each of my urls because I am new here and stackoverflow only allows 2 links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For that to happen your app should be set up in a folder called `www.thisisatest.com`. Setting that host name in the app's properties does not mean you access it through `http://IPADDRESS/www.thisisatest.com`. It means IIS will only route those requests to the app if the address used by the client is of the form `http://www.thisisatest.com/<querystring>`. Any other request will not be fulfilled. Try to remove that setting, this should allow you to access the app via `http://IPADDRESS/` or `http://MACHINENAME` (on Windows). On a Mac only the IP variant would normally work (unless the IIS machine is resovlable through a DNS).
2. Unless the port on which the website runs is blocked, the app should be accessible via IP. Of course there are other ways of blocking certain client IPs etc but if you didn't alter any default settings then it should work.

Comment: Thanks @CyberDude I did what you said to remove the hostname, but I had to change the port because port 80 is already in use. Now I can access my app anywhere using http://IPADDRESS:PORT. There are other issues like I can't insert values to the database from the mac machine, but I still have to investigate what's causing it becuase I'm using uploadify to store images in my db.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is not an answer to your question about IIS. I run my development sites on IIS Express, and needed to access a site running on IIS Express from my macbook pro and ipad. If you decide to switch from IIS to IIS Express, you can use this approach to access a site running in IIS Express from other machines on your network (including phones and tablets running over your WiFi DHCP).

First, follow [Scott Hanselman's Ninja guide to running your site on ports 80/443 over IIS Express](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx).

Then, find the IP of your VS win machine on your network. Today mine is 192.168.1.113.

Next, open MyDocuments/IISExpress/config/applicationhost.config. In Hanselman's article, you had to set `<binding>` sections here. Just add a new one for your IP. Here is what it might look like:

```
<bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1976:localhost" />
    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44376:localhost" />
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:HANSELMAN-W500" />
    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:HANSELMAN-W500" />
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:192.168.1.113" />
    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:192.168.1.113" />
</bindings>
```

After opening your firewall, start VS as an administrator, and run your site. If you can access it over http://localhost:1976, and http://HANSELMAN-W500 (or your computer name), you should then be able to access it from the mac or tablet using this URL:

```
http://192.168.1.113/
```

or, if you also set up SSL on port 443,

```
https://192.168.1.113/
```

You can also get this to work by running VS as a normal user instead of as an administrator. For that, you will have to run commands like the following:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://192.168.1.113:80/ user=everyone
netsh http add urlacl url=https://192.168.1.113:443/ user=everyone
```

... again, these commands (as well as how to undo them) are available on the Ninja article. After running them, IIS Express should start up from VS without having to run it as an administrator.

Comment: Thanks @danludwig I'll try this out. I heard good stuff about IISExpress as well but haven't tried it yet. Thanks